# Spring Select Parameter

Tags: java, spring, jsp, servlets, selection

I have a jsp which has a list of dynamically created drop down lists. There are 7 * N possible lists. I can successfully identify the first 7, but despite having different names, they repeat the same name N/7 times. So if I have 10 slots for 1 day, they have have the same id, where I want monday0, monday1, monday2 etc.

I should note that each of the path corresponds to an ArrayList in the Timetable class. In my controller, I'm going to be cycling through the parameters, adding them to a list, then overriding the list in the Timetable object and updating in Hibernate.

Here's my code

```
<sf:form id="details" method="post"
    action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/finalizeTimetable"
    commandName="timetable">
    <c:forEach begin="0" end="${count - 1}" varStatus="loop">
        <sf:select path="monday" id="monday${loop.index }">
            <sf:options items="${events }"/>
        </sf:select>

        <sf:select path="tuesday" id="tuesday${loop.index }">
            <sf:options items="${events }"/>
        </sf:select>

        <sf:select path="wednesday" id="wednesday${loop.index }">
            <sf:options items="${events }"/>
        </sf:select>

        <sf:select path="thursday" name="thursday${loop.index }">
            <sf:options items="${events }"/>
        </sf:select>

        <sf:select path="friday" name="friday${loop.index }">
            <sf:options items="${events }"/>
        </sf:select>

        <sf:select path="saturday" name="saturday${loop.index }">
            <sf:options items="${events }"/>
        </sf:select>

        <sf:select path="sunday" name="sunday${loop.index }">
            <sf:options items="${events }"/>
        </sf:select>
        <hr>
    </c:forEach>
    <input value="Submit" type="submit" />
</sf:form>
```

I have tried replacing name="day${loop.index}" with id, but same issue. It's probably something really small but it's bugging me!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed

```
<sf:select path="wednesday[${loop.index}]" id="wednesday${loop.index }" multiple="false">
            <sf:options items="${events }"/>
        </sf:select>
```